# from lxml import html(×)

Tags: python, pycharm, lxml

i have tried several versions about lxml for python3.6, but still report this error.
i need a detailed solution!!!!!

```
from lxml import html

C:\Users\17571\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Python/project/spider/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/project/spider/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lxml import html
  File "C:\Users\17571\venv\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .. import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的程序。

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Which Python did you use to create this venv? Was it Anaconda?

Comment: it has been solved after i used Anaconda, thank you